# How do I get warnings when using catkin tools?

Tags: ros, catkin-tools

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been using `catkin_make` for a while and am now testing `catkin_tools`.
I seems like the default configuration hides the warnings from the user, how do I print the warnings?

**catkin_make**

```
dell@M6700:~/test_workspace$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/dell/test_workspace
Source space: /home/dell/test_workspace/src
Build space: /home/dell/test_workspace/build
Devel space: /home/dell/test_workspace/devel
Install space: /home/dell/test_workspace/install
####
#### Running command: "cmake /home/dell/test_workspace/src -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/dell/test_workspace/devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/dell/test_workspace/install -G Unix Makefiles" in "/home/dell/test_workspace/build"
####
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.9.3
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.9.3
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/lib/ccache/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/lib/ccache/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/lib/ccache/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/lib/ccache/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/dell/test_workspace/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/dell/MEGAsync/catkin_workspace/devel;/opt/ros/indigo
-- This workspace overlays: /home/dell/MEGAsync/catkin_workspace/devel;/opt/ros/indigo
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python (found version "2.7.6") 
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/dell/test_workspace/build/test_results
-- Looking for include file pthread.h
-- Looking for include file pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.6.16
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
WARNING: Package "ompl" does not follow the version conventions. It should not contain leading zeros (unless the number is 0).
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 1 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - test_package
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'test_package'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(test_package)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;genlisp;genpy
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/dell/test_workspace/build
####
#### Running command: "make -j8 -l8" in "/home/dell/test_workspace/build"
####
Scanning dependencies of target test_node
[100%] Building CXX object test_package/CMakeFiles/test_node.dir/src/test_node.cpp.o
/home/dell/test_workspace/src/test_package/src/test_node.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
/home/dell/test_workspace/src/test_package/src/test_node.cpp:81:12: warning: unused variable ‘z’ [-Wunused-variable]
     double z;
            ^
Linking CXX executable /home/dell/test_workspace/devel/lib/test_package/test_node
[100%] Built target test_node
```

**Cleaning the workspace**

```
dell@M6700:~/test_workspace$ catkin clean -a
```

**catkin build**

```
dell@M6700:~/test_workspace$ catkin build
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Profile:                     default
Extending:             [env] /home/dell/MEGAsync/catkin_workspace/devel:/opt/ros/indigo
Workspace:                   /home/dell/test_workspace
Source Space:       [exists] /home/dell/test_workspace/src
Build Space:        [exists] /home/dell/test_workspace/build
Devel Space:        [exists] /home/dell/test_workspace/devel
Install Space:     [missing] /home/dell/test_workspace/install
DESTDIR:                     None
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Isolate Develspaces:         False
Install Packages:            False
Isolate Installs:            False
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Additional CMake Args:       None
Additional Make Args:        None
Additional catkin Make Args: None
Internal Make Job Server:    True
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Whitelisted Packages:        None
Blacklisted Packages:        None
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Workspace configuration appears valid.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Found '1' packages in 0.0 seconds. 
Starting ==> test_package                                                                                                                                                               
Finished <== test_package [ 8.3 seconds ]                                                                                                                                               
[build] Finished.                                                                                                                                                                       
[build] Runtime: 8.3 seconds
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/230717/how-do-i-get-warnings-when-using-catkin-tools?/) by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1505 on 2016-04-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to the following link (https://github.com/catkin/catkin_tools/issues/53), there is a " -v " option to use with catkin build that will print you more informations.

---

Originally posted by [F.Brosseau](https://answers.ros.org/users/22477/f.brosseau/) with karma: 379 on 2016-04-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on 2016-04-02**:
Note that newer versions of catkin_tools will print warnings without any switch (https://github.com/catkin/catkin_tools/issues/308)

**Comment by [F.Brosseau](https://answers.ros.org/users/22477/f.brosseau/) on 2016-04-04**:
Good to know, I don't really use this tool for the moment.